# Scrapy how to print result from yield immediately

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Function `parse` scrapes the link in the first page. Function`parse_product` scrapes the details in the next page and check if there is a 3rd page to be scraped. Function `parse_finalreport` scrapes the details in the 3rd page. The problem I am facing is that the 3rd function `parse_finalreport`'s output is printed last together.  I want result like this:

```
dfgcontactperson
year
abstract

dfgcontactperson
empty
empty

dfgcontactperson
year
abstract
```

but the result i get is like this:

```
dfgcontactperson

dfgcontactperson
empty
empty

dfgcontactperson

year
abstract
year
abstract
```

My code:

```
 def parse(self,response):
  for row in response.xpath('//div[contains(@class,"eintrag")]'):
        link = row.xpath('.//h2/a/@href').extract()
        link = ['https://gepris.dfg.de' + item + '?language=en' for item in link]
        for p in link:
            yield scrapy.Request(p,callback=self.parse_product)

def parse_product(self, response):
   dfgcontactperson = response.xpath('//div[@class="dfg_contact"]/span[@class="value"]/span/a/text()').extract()
   print(dfgcontactperson)
   finalreport = response.xpath('//ul[@class="tab1"]/li[@id="tabbutton2"]/a/@href').extract()
        finalreport = ['https://gepris.dfg.de' + item + '?language=en' for item in finalreport]
        if not finalreport:
            print('empty')
            print('empty')
        for x in finalreport:
            yield scrapy.Request(x,callback=self.parse_finalreport)

 def parse_finalreport(self,response):
        year = response.xpath('//div[@id="projektbeschreibung"]//span[contains(text(),"Final Report Year")]/following-sibling::span//text()').extract()
        abstract = response.xpath('//div[@id="projektbeschreibung"]/h4[contains(text(),"Abstract")]/following-sibling::p/text()').extract()
        print(year)
        print(abstract)
```

Comment: Why do you want to print that in the first place?

Comment: i want to pass the output to my C# app

Comment: Have you considered using [feed exports](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/feed-exports.html)?